# Having 'RNCSafeAreaProvider' Error on snack.io

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to test an example on Snack.io, but i am experiencing this error:
[image]

Has anyboday have this issue before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same when i try to run this example that was linked to the react-navigation 5 docs. So i changed the expo version to 38 then error gone.

[image]